# Changing root controller of a tab bar's navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I have a tab bar in my app and one of the buttons is "Profile" which should present one VC if user not authorized and another if user already authorized. [image: profile image]

So... Things work, but not correctly. Looks like I messed up some root controllers. Sometimes I cant pop up vc or change the color of a nav bar title.

I create a custom navigation controller with that code inside

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userId") != nil {
    let newController: UserViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userViewController") as! UserViewController
    self.setViewControllers([newController], animated: false)
} else {
    let newController: LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.setViewControllers([newController], animated: false) 
}
```

Is there a way to implement in correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a Navigation Controller - which (as @PierreMB had mentioned) won't work. You should instead create two regular View Controllers with storyboard ID's "userViewController" and "loginViewController", and instantiate them.

Create a UINavigationController subclass, and put this code (which you wrote, slightly modified) in its viewWillAppear() method (as a bonus, you can pass the 'animated' parameter free of charge):

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userId") != nil {
    let newController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userViewController") // drop the 'as! UINavigationController'
    self.setViewControllers([newController], animated: animated)
} else {
    let newController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") // drop the 'as! UINavigationController'
    self.setViewControllers([newController], animated: animated) 
}
```

The function instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier() by default returns a UIViewController, which is what you really want to display.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to put a UINavigationController as a root of another UINavigationController ? Because it is prohibited and doesn't work well.

Comment: No, tabBar -- seque -- > nav controller --> login controllers
And than.. Im trying to find a solution to implement a switching between two controllers after nav controller

Comment: Isn't `self` the custom navigation controller, in other words a subclass of UINavigationController ?